# Tiling divs inside a wrapping div rather than have them appear outside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a series of tiles inside a wrapping div element. At the moment, they appear inside the wrapping div and then overflow outside the div instead of wrapping horizontally and appearing as tiles. Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cgMGM/).

To give an example of how they should look, take a look at the Windows Metro interface where the tiles wrap around to a new column:
[image]
Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: #238d9a;
}

#metro {
    width: 960px;
    height: 340px;
    background: #004050;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.tile {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to add

```
display:inline-block;
```

To your tiles. I've updated the jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cgMGM/1/

An alternative is to add `float:left;` but inline-block is preferred in this case to prevend the #metro div from losing height and prevents the need for extra .clear-fix nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
.tile{
      word-wrap: break-word;
      }
```

And now you can use this class in your div